# CoreText: Space between lines

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-text

How I can know what is the size between two lines?
I'm using CoreText API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does line spacing work in Core Text? (and why is it different from NSLayoutManager?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511830/how-does-line-spacing-work-in-core-text-and-why-is-it-different-from-nslayoutm)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511830/how-does-line-spacing-work-in-core-text-and-why-is-it-different-from-nslayoutm.

Answer (score 2):

Try CTFontGetLeading(aCTFont).

Comment: Do you have any ideas why it can always return 0?